# Rails: Why do I get "warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION" when running rake cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5

I've just set up a Linux Mint box for rails development with rvm. I went ahead and generated a Rails 5 app, set up the mysql connection, added the [cucumber-rails gem](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/rails) and then tried to run:

```
rake cucumber
```

For some reason, I was met with:

```
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -S bundle exec cucumber --profile default
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_ARRAY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of VERSION_ARRAY was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_MAJOR
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/version.rb:5: warning: previous definition of VERSION_MAJOR was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_MINOR
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of VERSION_MINOR was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/version.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_BUILD
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/version.rb:7: warning: previous definition of VERSION_BUILD was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:99: warning: already initialized constant JSON::NaN
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/common.rb:99: warning: previous definition of NaN was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:101: warning: already initialized constant JSON::Infinity
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/common.rb:101: warning: previous definition of Infinity was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:103: warning: already initialized constant JSON::MinusInfinity
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/common.rb:103: warning: previous definition of MinusInfinity was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:128: warning: already initialized constant JSON::UnparserError
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.5/lib/json/common.rb:128: warning: previous definition of UnparserError was here
```

This is, to my knowledge, a fairly plain vanilla installation, so I cannot understand what I've done to earn these warnings. Do I somehow have conflicting gems in place? If so, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Judging by the trace you are using globally installed ruby. Did you use rvm to install it globally?

Comment: @IvanKolmychek, I've got the ruby package installed and I subsequently installed rvm. Ruby is available globally, yes. Am I answering your question?

Comment: I get this issue too, but I don't have a solution. Doubt that globally installed Ruby is likely to be an issue - I'm using rbenv.

Comment: For the record, I did not ever find a solution, but rather proceeded with building a rails 4 app instead. I'll surely revisit one day-but not today

Comment: I am getting this same error, thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting this issue too, only when running rspec tests using guard, Rails 5

Comment: Some gem in your Gemfile is depending on the `json` gem, but the `json` gem is probably also installed globally on your machine. Add the `json` gem to your Gemfile with `bundle add json`, run `bundle install` and these warnings should be gone.

Answer (score 39):

I managed to get rid of the JSON warnings by:

```
bundle clean --force
bundle
```

Comment: This command resolved my issues `bundle clean --force && bundle update --force`

Answer (score 5):

The json gem that came with your version of Ruby is a little outdated. If you want to get rid of these warnings, you have to include a more up to date version of it in your Gemfile:

`gem 'json', '>= 2.0.0'`

Then run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 4):

[redshift5's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420106/10907864) worked for me. Just to add more context.

I had this same issue while working on an application with **Rails 6**.

I was getting warnings like this:

```
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_ARRAY
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/version.rb:5: warning: previous definition of VERSION_ARRAY was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_MAJOR
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of VERSION_MAJOR was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/version.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_MINOR
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/version.rb:7: warning: previous definition of VERSION_MINOR was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/version.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_BUILD
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/version.rb:8: warning: previous definition of VERSION_BUILD was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:100: warning: already initialized constant JSON::NaN
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/common.rb:130: warning: previous definition of NaN was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant JSON::Infinity
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/common.rb:132: warning: previous definition of Infinity was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:104: warning: already initialized constant JSON::MinusInfinity
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.5.1/lib/json/common.rb:134: warning: previous definition of MinusInfinity was here
/home/promisechukwuenyem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:129: warning: already initialized constant JSON::UnparserError
```

**Things I tried**:

1. I tried removing my `Gemfile.lock` file and trying to do a fresh `bundle install` but that did not fix it.
2. I tried to uninstall all gem versions of `puma` and `jsonapi-serializer` from my computer and reinstalling them, but that did not fix it.

**Here's how I fixed**:

First I ran the command below to force clean up unused gems in the bundler directory even if `--path` is set:

```
bundle clean --force
```

Next, I ran the command below to reinstall my gems for the project:

```
bundle install
```

OR

```
bundle update
```

OR

```
bundle update --force
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**.